# How to clip a variable sized widget into a fixed size in flutter?

Tags: flutter

I'm having a bunch of widgets (dynamically sized) in a ListView, and I want each of those widgets to be exactly 300 pixels. How is it possible?
(Note: Using SizedBox along with BoxFit.contain makes some of widgets too small; I want it to be cropped).

Answer (score 0):

Use BoxFit.cover instead of contain to crop it. BoxFit.contain will shrink it to fit in its parent.

For more info check this out
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/BoxFit-class.html